# PHP: How to fetch data from database?

Tags: php, sql

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['id']="id";
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Update</title>
</head>
<body>

<table border="2">
    <tr>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Edit</th>
    </tr>
<?php
     $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","telephasic");
     $q2="select * from register where id = '".$_SESSION['id']."'";
     $run=mysqli_query($conn, $q2);
     while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run))
     {
         $name=$row[1];
         $email=$row[2];
     ?>

    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $name; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $email; ?></td>
        <td><a href="edit.php"> Edit </a></td>
    </tr>
 <?php } ?>
 </table> 
 </body>
```

here i want to fetch an individual row information stored in database i can't able to fetch the data so what i have to do here for fetch code with help of session id

Comment: what error do you get ? @Arun Sharma

Comment: So you get no data in return or data just doesn't show up? Have you checked that `$row[1]` is valid and contains data?

Comment: why `$row[1]...` ? I guess u need something like `$row['name']`...

Comment: i did that but also not working

Comment: _i did that but also not working..._ just use var_dump($row) to see its structure

Comment: Print your SQL query and try to run that in your any client tool (Like MySql Workbench) which you are using to access database

Comment: The sql query you have is trying to retrieve an entry that has the string "id" as a value for the id field. Is it actually what you want to do?

Comment: $_SESSION['id']="id"; what is this "id"?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
session_start();
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Update</title>
</head>
<body>

<table border="2">
    <tr>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Edit</th>
    </tr>
<?php
     $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","telephasic");
     $q2 = "select * from register where id = $id ";
     $run = mysqli_query($conn, $q2);
     $row = mysqli_fetch_array($run);
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?= $row['name']; ?></td>
        <td><?= $row['email']; ?></td>
        <td><a href="edit.php"> Edit </a></td>
    </tr>
 </table> 
 </body>
```

skip the while part, cuz you are fetching single record.

Comment: but it can only fetch data of 1st id only i have to fetch data of the person login

Comment: simply assign the user id in $_SESSION['id'] variable .
i recommend to create session id when user login, and use that session variable.
i already edited the code.

Answer (score 0):

you have problem at the third row in code

```
$_SESSION['id']="id";
```

you set the $_SESSION['id'] to the string "id", so you will get nothing from your database cause you have no row that have id = "id" . remove this line and everything will work fine

Comment: but i cannot fetch the row info

Comment: use mysqli_fetch_row not mysqli_fetch_array at line 23

Comment: and put the second <tr> section inside the while loop